# In general, is there an easy way (perhaps a tool) to match assembly binding versions with their manifest definitions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In general, is there an easy way (perhaps a tool) to match assembly binding versions with their manifest definitions?

I'm tired of hunting down mismatched assemblies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget's [Add-BindingRedirect](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) cmdlet does that for you. You need to run it from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.